# Is it possible to vectorize a multiplication in VC++ without SSE4?

Tags: x86, sse, simd

I want to vectorize a multiplication operation. I tried using `_mm_mul_epi32`, but my CPU has only support for the "MMX, SSE (1,2,3,3S), EM64T" instruction.

Can someone please tell if I can try another function?

Comment: Check out my library for SSE2 integer multipication: https://github.com/LiraNuna/glsl-sse2/blob/master/source/ivec4.h#L404

Comment: glsl-sse2 looks interesting but I could not figure out the code license.  Did I miss something?  If you have not chosen a license and your intent is to share freely, I'd suggest taking a look at the boost software license.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the range of your multiplicands - it they fit within 16 bits then there are a number of 16 x 16 bit multiple SSE instructions available prior to SSE4 (e.g. `mm_madd_epi16`, `mm_mulhi_epi16`, `mm_mullo_epi16`, `mm_mulhrs_epi16`, etc).

If you need 32 bit operands but they are unsigned then you can use `mm_mul_epu32`.

Alternatively you may convert to float, and use `_mm_mul_ps` (integer <-> float conversion in SSE is quite efficient, and the cost may be justified if it gets you a 4x SIMD throughput improvement).

Comment: It's nothing personal, I "stalk" anyone who posts about SSE, SIMD etc. ;-)